# Get rid of "Trying to get property of non-object" with Auth::user()->id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am making a workflow application in Laravel.

Users can CRUD tasks, projects, users and orgs.

There are about 16-20 screens/functions users can do.

I use `Auth::user()->id` to determine who the current user is and get their tasks, projects, etc.

This works great if a visitor is logged in.

If a visitor to the site is not logged in, Laravel returns a big black and orange stack dump with the error "Trying to get property of non-object."

How do I engineer this so that if a visitor is logged in, Laravel returns a table of their, say, open tasks, and if they're not, it returns a page with an empty table?

Answer (score 1):

With `Auth::check()` http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
    // Maybe add a Redirect::to()
} else {
    // User is not logged in...
}
```

Comment: Hi SamV.  I've got that logic in a couple of my views to determine if the view should, say, show the login form or a logged-in user's name.  I'll experiment today with putting that in controllers and/or models.

Comment: @AndrewKoper Do not put it in the models, use it in a route filter or within a controller. I would recommend having a route group with the auth filter. So if the user is not logged in it will redirect them to a public area. Take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Comment: But that's the thing: I don't want a route filter that I think will render the page if the visitor is logged in and will redirect the visitor to a login page if they're not.  It's very important to me and this application that non-users see the functionality available and how easy the application is to use and convert to users.

Comment: @AndrewKoper Ok, do whatever you think is best - I would assume that the only method would be controllers/views.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. Somehow laravel by default accepts id as primary key for its Auth Table if you changed the user table primary key modify your model as follows.

Add this protected `$primaryKey = 'your_custom_primary_key';`

Comment: Very well, I have this problem but with  `Id` in my table and `id` in laravel scripts